# Why does this promise not behave as expected?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm struggling to understand why after calling `updateStatus()` I see 'promise resolved' logged to the console, but not 'refreshGames'. How is the promise resolved if the code inside `refreshGames()` never runs?

```
var refreshGames = function() {
  console.log('refreshGames');
  var defer = $q.defer();
  playersService.getGames({
    playerId: playerId
  }).$promise.then(function(data) {
    vm.games = data;

    return defer.promise;
  });
};

var updateStatus = function() {
  $q.all([refreshGames.promise]).then(function() {
    console.log('promise resolved');
    populateOptions(vm.games);
    vm.tableParams.reload();
  });
};
```

Comment: hint: `refreshGames.promise` returns `undefined`.

Comment: http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your function `refreshGames` returns nothing, it should return the promise and the defer must be resolved, like this:

```
var refreshGames = function() {
  console.log('refreshGames');
  var defer = $q.defer();
  playersService.getGames({
    playerId: playerId
  }).$promise.then(function(data) {
    vm.games = data;

    defer.resolve(data);
  });

  return defer.promise;
};
```

and in the `$q.all` you just do `refreshGames()`

Answer (score 2):

`refreshGames.promise` is `undefined` - there's no code anywhere that creates this property on refreshGames

any non-promise in $q.all is promisified and effectively equivalent to Promise.resolve(n) (or however you do that with $q

so, your $q.all is essentially

```
$q.all([undefined]).then(function() {
   ...
});
```

and thus gets executed immediately